# Prime ideals and maximal ideals of the Pullback of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, pullback

Let $A,B,C$ be commutative Noetherian rings with given surjective ring homomorphisms $f:A\twoheadrightarrow C $ and $g: B \twoheadrightarrow C$. Let $A\times_C B:=\{(a,b)\in A \times B : f(a)=g(b)\}$ ( with the subring structure induced from $A \times B$ ) be the Pullback (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory) ).

Is there a good description of the prime ideals or maximal ideals of $A\times_C B$ in terms of ideals of $A,B$ and $C$ ?

Comment: it is the pushout of the prime spectra of $A$ and $B$ along the prime spectrum of $C$.

Comment: @quantum: push out of the corresponding spectrum in which category ? certainly it can't be in the category of sets ...

Comment: Not category of sets but of topological spaces. Anyway the underlying set would be this (I believe). It shouldn't be too far from and the rough reason is because the images and preimages of a ring from a (commutative unitary) ring homomorphism are all rings.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\spec{\mathrm{Spec}}$**Hint**: You may be inspired by pure product, which is a special type of fiber product when $C=0$ (the zero ring). In this case the prime ideals are all the elements in the product of $\spec A\cup \{A\}$ and $\spec B \cup \{B\}$ without $A\times B$.

Since your homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow C$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$ are surjective it is easier to describe this (this is a general construction and we did not need $A$ and $B$ Noetherian), since the projections $A\times_C B \rightarrow A$ and $A\times_C B \rightarrow B$ of prime ideals in $A\times_C B$ are either prime ideals or the whole ring.

Things become more messier if $f$ or $g$ were not surjective.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your hint, but it seems to me that prime ideals should be of the form $P_1 \times P_2$ with $P_1$ a prime ideal of $A$ and $P_2$ prime in $B$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, than your hint is wrong: consider the ideal $(0)$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which is prime since the ring is a field. In the product $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ the product ideal $(0)\times (0)=((0,0))$ is not prime, since the ring is not an integral domain.

Comment: I did not say that if $P_1$ is a prime ideal of $A$ and $P_2$ is a prime ideal of $B$ then $P_1\times P_2$ is the prime ideal of $A\times B$. What I said is: The canonical projections of a prime ideal $P$ in $A\times B$ is either a prime ideal or the whole ring it is projected to. So for $A\times B$ the prime ideals are of the form $P_1\times B$ or $A\times P_2$ and their canonical projections are $P_1$ or $A$ (projection on $A$) and $B$ or $P_2$ (projection on $B$).

Comment: I can see that the prime ideals of $A\times B$ are of the form $\mathfrak p\times B,A\times\mathfrak q$ with $\mathfrak p,\mathfrak q$ prime; that argument uses that $(1,0),(0,1)\in A\times B$, which is not necessarily the case for $A\times_C B$. So how can we conclude from the information about the projections $A\times_C B\to A$ and $A\times_C B\to B$ how the primes of $A\times_C B$ look like?

Comment: @Sha Can you provide an example of the fiber product for which $f$ and $g$ are surjective and the projection of a prime ideal is not a prime? The projections of a prime ideal of the fiber product is a prime because we assumed $f$ and $g$ are surjections. The proof is very similar to the projection of a prime ideal of $A\times B$.

Comment: I don't disagree with the fact that the projection of a prime is prime, but I don't see how the argument is similar. So say we have a prime $Q$ of $A\times_C B$ such that projecting to $A$ yields the prime $\mathfrak p$ and projection to $B$ yields the prime $\mathfrak q$. Then what? The proof can't be similar as for $A\times B$, because there we crucially use that $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ belongs to the prime of $A\times B$.