# Prime ideals of pullbacks of commutative rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, pullback

Let $A,B,C$ be commutative rings with given ring homomorphisms $f:A\rightarrow C $ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. Let $A\times_C B:=\{(a,b)\in A \times B : f(a)=g(b)\}$ be their [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)) (with the subring structure induced from $A \times B$).

Is there a good description of the prime ideals or maximal ideals of $A \times_C B$ in terms of the ideals of $A,B$ and $C$?

Thank you.

Motivated by this question: [Prime ideals and maximal ideals of the Pullback of rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255466/prime-ideals-and-maximal-ideals-of-the-pullback-of-rings)

Comment: I have deleted the wrong tag "homological algebra" (it does not fit) and fixed some formatting.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A \to C$ is surjective, then we have
$$\mathrm{Spec}(A \times_C B) = \mathrm{Spec}(A) \sqcup_{\mathrm{Spec}(C)} \mathrm{Spec}(B)$$
in the category of topological spaces, even in the category of ringed spaces (as well as in the category of schemes). This gives an explicit description of the points. In fact, $\mathrm{Spec}(B) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(A \times_C B)$ is a closed immersion, and the complement is isomorphic to the complement of $\mathrm{Spec}(C) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(A)$, so that as sets we have (which I denote by $|-|$)
$$|\mathrm{Spec}(A \times_C B)| \cong |\mathrm{Spec}(B)| \sqcup |\mathrm{Spec}(A) \setminus \mathrm{Spec}(C)|.$$

Proofs, details and examples:

> Karl Schwede, *Gluing Schemes and a Scheme without Close Points*,  Contemporary Mathematics 386, 157, [pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Eschwede/Papers/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf)

If $A \to C$ and $B \to C$ are not surjective, I don't think that we can say much. For example, let $A \subseteq C$ be a subring, $f$ be the inclusion, then $A \times_C B \cong \{b \in B : g(b) \in A\}$, and I doubt that we can say much about its prime ideals - it is just a subring of $B$, and every subring of $B$ has this form (consider $g = \mathrm{id}_B$).

Comment: thank you Martin. Do you know an algebraic proof for the case that A→C  is surjective not using topology?

Comment: Have you read the paper? Of course it's algebra in the end.